# How to pick a "center" of a concave polygon?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polygons, homothety

I asked a question on how to [scale concave polygons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094996/how-to-scale-a-polygon-such-that-all-the-points-lie-within-the-original-polygon) and a couple of people suggested some very clever solutions.

The issue is that these solutions rely on picking an appropriate point $C$ in the interior of the polygon.

The problem, more clearly, is to find a point $C$ in the interior of a polygon, such that every half segment connecting that point and the vertices of the polygon never intersects the Boundary of the polygon.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

In the first picture the point is a perfect candidate, in the second, the point is not because the red edge passes through a section outside the control polygon.

For now we can assume such a point exists, although for some shapes such point will not exist and so a more complex curve is needed.

Comment: What you're talking about are called _star-shaped polygons_; they're the simplest category of concave polygons and there's a fair amount of literature about them (including how to find a star point if one exists, I believe) that you should be able to find from that name.

Comment: The concerned domain is "computational geometry" and you are dealing with the  "art gallery problem" https://brilliant.org/wiki/guarding-a-museum/