# How to scale a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry, polytopes

I want to scale down the polyhedron by a given factor as shown below, where polyhedron is defined by $n_i(x-x_i) = 0, i=0,...,5$. That can be formulated as \begin{equation}
    P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a_i^Tx \leq b_i, \; i=1,...,5\}
\end{equation}

Any idea to achieve this is really appreciated
[image]

Comment: Can this be of help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094996/how-to-scale-a-polygon-such-that-all-the-points-lie-within-the-original-polygon/3095058#3095058

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thanks I will check and let you know